# Executing a php function in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

In the below script an input which holds a token value is generated once the user has click the submit button and where no errors are present. Then I want to post that value inside the php page so that I can use it in my query. Here the input value is generated successfully but posting its value to the php page and executing the php page is the issue (i elaborate a bit below)
below is the script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('code');

    var appendedStripeToken = false;

var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#payment-form');

    if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
                $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);

    } else {
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        handleCall(token);
    }
};

function handleCall(token) { 
   var $form = $('#payment-form');
    if (!appendedStripeToken) { 
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
$form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        appendedStripeToken = true; 
        phpCall(); 

    } 
}

function onSubmit() {
    var $form = $('#payment-form'); // TODO: give your html-form-tag an "id" attribute and type this id in this line. IMPORTANT: Don't replace the '#'!

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
  // TODO: give your html-submit-input-tag an "id" attribute

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
}


function phpCall() {
 if( appendedStripeToken === true ){
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {run: true},
    url: 'functions/paymentEmail.php',
    success: function (response) {//response is value returned from php (for    your example it's "bye bye"
                  $('#payment-form').prop('disabled', true); // TODO: give your html-submit-input-tag an "id" attribute

        alert(response);
    }
   });
 }
} 
  </script>
```

Now take a particular look at this part

```
url: 'functions/paymentEmail.php',
    success: function (response) {//response is value returned from php (for    your example it's "bye bye"
                  $('#payment-form').prop('disabled', true); // TODO: give your html-submit-input-tag an "id" attribute

        alert(response);
```

I do not want the php function to be executed with an alert box, because it will not run.
[image]

below is the php code:

```
     <?php


        $course_price_final = $_POST['course_price_final'];
        $course_token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
        $course_provider = $_POST['course_provider'];
        $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
        $course_delivery = $_POST['course_delivery'];
        $order_date = date("Y-m-d");
        $insert_c = "insert into orders (course_title,course_price_final,course_provider,user_email,course_date,course_delivery,order_date,course_token) 
                 values ('$crs_title','$course_price_final','$course_provider','$user_email','$course_date1','$course_delivery','$order_date','$course_token')";
        $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c);

        $location = "../paymentConfirmed.php";


    header( "Location: $location" );

?>
```

Comment: I think you are overusing AJAX. AJAX is needed to create dynamic pages, where some functionality is done on the server so you don't have to refresh the page. Why not just create a form and submit it? That way if it is successful, do a redirect. Your method just seems overkill.

Comment: I know its various complications that led me to this situation. I could elaborate for paragraphs on why but right im just trying to move forward

Comment: So you want to display the response from the redirect? Well, you can probably insert  all of that HTML into the document, overriding the old one. If you care about the url that is displayed, you can either use history.pushState(null, null, xhr.responseURL) in browsers that support both history.pushState and the responseURL property, I don't know how to get the responseURL property with jQuery though (if it's not possible, you'd have to use vanilla JS for that). Or like the answer suggested, you can use `window.location = response`, but you'd have to return the actual URL in your PHP script.

Comment: Also, instead of using the XHR object responseURL, you can hard-code the url that the script redirects to into `history.pushState`. Just an idea, but that's probably over-complicating everything a little bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make a redirect using ajax you can  return a url, than make a `window.location = response`

Comment: This kind of beats the purpose of using AJAX

Comment: thanks for your responses. it however does not seem to work properly: it just translate the world document and add it as such the url<!DOCTYPE%20html><html><head><link%20rel="shortcurt%20icon"%20href="content/icon.png">%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20<link%20href="cssPaper/bootstrap.min.css"%20rel="stylesheet"%20media="screen">%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20<link%20href="css/mystyle.css"%20rel="stylesheet"%20med

Comment: Remove it header( "Location: $location" ); from your file and return a valid url

Comment: what do you mean a valid url?

Comment: You must return `$location` I see it's your url

Comment: whats preventing me from using this php variable, and out of curiosity my query doesnt seem to run almost like the php/mysql code is almost ignored

Comment: In order to do it that way, you should remove `header( "Location: $location" );` and add `echo $location;` as the last line in your PHP code.

Comment: As for your query not working, do you see any errors logged in your log files? Also, your query doesn't look very safe.

Comment: thank you. it seems that all of the php code are ignored though such as <b>Notice</b>:%20%20Undefined%20index:%20course_price_final%20in%20, so I am thinking that i would have to post those variables using ajax. safety is critical to me how could i make the query safer?

Comment: Oh yeah, you should send your values over to your php script with the AJAX call. And to make it safer, you should either escape the `$_POST` variables with [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or better yet, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). Note also that the client can modify which values are sent to the PHP script via POST (if they modify the code), as in, they could modify the 'course final price' value, so you have to take that into account server-side also.

Comment: sorry i am quite novice, how would i send my values over using my php script wtih the ajax call? lets say i have input name="user_price" how would i grab this value and store it so then the query would run

Comment: Hmm, add an id to that, like so:  `<input type="text" name="user_price" id="user_price">` and then just, in your AJAX call, in the data parameter: `data: { run: true, user_price: $('#user_price').val() }`. You can get the input by its name or by the form it belongs to, etc... but I find it more straightforward to just use an id.

Comment: okay so if i had 3 parameters it would be  user_price: $('user_price').val(),  user_price: $('user_price').val(),  user_price: $('user_price').val() } right?

Comment: No, you'd have to give an unique name to each parameter, and an unique id to each input, so you get the value for each different input. Repeating the same paremeter name will just override the previous ones that are named the same way. So, more like: `data: { user_price1: $('#user_price1').val(), user_price2: $('#user_price2').val(), user_price3: $('#user_price3').val() }`

Comment: oh i know a unique name, but is format generally correct, name1,name2,name3}

Comment: Yeah, that's the correct format. You're passing an object to the `data` property of the AJAX call, and that's the syntax for objects.

Comment: Either way, using a simple HTML form to submit the stuff would be probably a much better and simpler idea. I don't know what the complications are with your current code, but you should consider restructuring it. Just a suggestion though. Getting all the concepts at first might be not so easy, but it comes with time. You should read more on basic HTML and PHP, SQL injection, JavaScript, forms, etc. I know it all seemed confusing to me at first :)